# it has been known that

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

Is "known" a correct word choice in the following?

> It has long been known that Fruit A contains an enormous amount of vitamin C. However, recent research has disproved this conventional wisdom.

By describing something as "known," the speaker is committed to its truth. By saying it has been "disproved," the speaker is committed to its non-truth. To acknowledge something is a truth and has been disproved is a gross incompatibility in the speaker's belief, isn't it?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  Is there some reason why you thought it wasn't fine?

Comment: From a common use and English perspective, yes. From a philosophical perspective, perhaps not. Are you arguing that it's not possible to **know** something if it's actually false? ("I know it's this way." *something disproves it* "Oh, I guess I didn't know that after all.") But then what's the status of *anything* being known—assuming it could be disproved? That's an interesting discussion, but it belongs at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford By describing something as "known," isn't the speaker committed to its truth? If it is a truth, how can  it be disproved at all? To claim something is a truth and has been disproved is a gross incompatibility on the speaker's part, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said this could be a philosophical question. We "knew" the earth was flat—until it was proven not to be. Now we "know" it's round. (Unless something else happens at some point that proves something else.) What else do we "know" that could actually be proven wrong? Should the word itself be removed from our lexicography?

Comment: You can assert that **known** isn't the correct word here because of this. In which case, you're likely looking for **believed**. (But it's grammatical, and it arguably *is* correct, depending on your philosophical viewpoint.)

Comment: Did you look up _know_ in a [dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/know)? It doesn’t always mean “proven as an undisputed truth.”

Comment: The word "know" presupposes that the speaker is committed to the truth of something, but the word 'disprove" presupposes that the speaker is committed to the non-truth of something. That's the problem.

Comment: What we "know" to be true may turn out to be false in the future, but that does not affect our use of "know" because we use "know" to show our current commitment to its truth.

Comment: The problem with the OP sentence is that there is a contradiction on the part of the speaker's belief. Although what we know to be true may prove false in the future, we cannot be committed to the truth and non-truth of something at the same time.

Comment: @Apollyon - Why are you adding all these details as comments? Why not add them into your question, and transform your cursory, hasty question into one that is rich in detail and well thought out? You've been an active member of this community for over four years now, long enough to know how much we appreciate detailed questions: [_Remember to make an effort to research your question before posting it, and be sure to add as much detail as you can when explaining your problem. The more you can tell us, the better answers you'll receive!_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem becomes clearer when you use the simple past.  The present perfect softens the problem a little.

> It was long known that the world was flat.

You could put **known** in quotation marks to indicate irony or sarcasm:

> It was long "known" that the world was flat.

But in normal expository prose without irony it would be:

> It was long believed that the world was flat.
>
> It had long been thought that the world was flat.
>
> It had long been held that the world was flat.